# Convergence ansd Sobolev Space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $J$ an function $\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ defined by 
$$
J(t)
=
\begin{cases}
0 &: |t| \leq 1\\
t &: |t| \geq 2
\end{cases}
$$
and $|J(t)| \leq |t|$. We consider that $u \in H^1(a,b)$ such that $u(a)=u(b)=0$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}^*$, we put $u_n = \dfrac{J(nu)}{n}$.
we now that $u_n$ converge to $u$ in $H^1(a,b)$, and $u_n \in H^1(a,b)$, and we know that support $u_n$ is compact in $]a,b[$

How w prouve that $u_n \in H^1_0(a,b)$?

Comment: There is something wrong in the definition of $J(t)$.

Comment: sorry, i edit the definition of the function $J$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that $u(a) = u(b) = 0$ and $u$ is continuous, there is $\epsilon$ small so that $u(x)< 1/n$ for $x \in (a, a+\epsilon)$ and $x\in (b-\epsilon , b)$.  Thus $nu(x) <1$ and so $u_n(x) = 0$ for $x\in (a, a+\epsilon) \cup (b-\epsilon , b)$. Thus $u_n \in C_c(a, b)$. Then by taking convolution with a standard mollifier, we have

$$u_n * \phi_m \to u_n$$

in $H^1(a, b)$ and $u_n * \phi_m \in C^\infty_c(a, b)$. Thus $u_n \in H_0^1(a, b)$.

Comment: Please, tell me who's $\phi_m$?

Comment: Can you tell me please why we choose $u(x) < 1/n$ and where we use $u_n(x)=0$? I thin that we use these all to prouve that support $u_n$ is compact. And who's $\phi_m$? what it's definition?

Comment: To construct a mollifier $\phi_m$, first take a smooth positive function $\phi$ with support in $(-1,  1)$ and $\int \phi = 1$. Then $\phi_m (x) := m\phi(mx)$. @hin